# Wide Character Font Rendering in Windows Browsers

Tags: browser, fonts, rendering

I made a custom font to display text so that it looks like the keys on a computer keyboard and embedded it in a website.

https://googledrive.com/host/0B9zaRHzo-vktWUZUcVptR1M0OWM/test2.html

All is good on MacOS, but the wide characters render incorrectly on Chrome, IE and FF on Windows.  Is this a bug with the browsers? Is something wrong with the font?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to check: you're talking about the "Keys" font, not the Legni font, correct?